# Inserting into a std::Multimap of std::Map (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, insert

If I have a `std::multimap<int, std::map<int, MyClass>> myMultimap` how to I insert a class object `MyClassA` into the map with value `1` at multimap value `2`?

It looks like I can do `myMultimap.at(2).insert(std::pair<1,MyClassA>);` in c++11 but I am using c++98 due to a library regression/incomparability out of my control.

I've also tried

```
myMultimap[2].insert(
            std::make_pair(
                myMultimap[2].end(),
                myClassA
            )
        );
```

which gives: `error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::multimap<int, std::map<int, ns_namespace::MyClassType> >’ and ‘int’)|` for both of the `[`...`]`'s.

I don't want to do something like `myMultimap.insert(std::make_pair(2,std::make_pair(1,MyClassA)))`
because if I understand correctly, this would make a new map in the multimap rather than assigning the class object to the existing map within the multimap.

Comment: `multimap` and `at`/`[]` doesn't make sense. Think about it. Really think about it.

Comment: with a multimap you can have multiple entries with key value 2. which one of these has the map that you want to insert your object in? that's the question -- decide!

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Is there a way to do something similar to the .at() but using an iterator? (also, I just realised C++11 added .at to map, not multimap, whoops)

Comment: such as .find(3) returns an iterator, and then use that to access the map?

Comment: A map of maps is likely already the wrong direction! Tes, you can use data structures like this but they are unlikely to be particular useful. I'd guess, a map indexed by a pair of integers is a much better fit.

Comment: _"how to I insert ... at multimap value 2?"_  **Which** multimap value 2?  The "multi" means that you don't know that there's a single "2" key.

Comment: sorry, at "iterator value" 2 not actual memory offset 2

Answer (score 0):

It is a two stage process:

1. Locate the position in the outer map where you want to do something to the inber map. If necessary, insert a new element.
2. Update the inner map withthe appropriatevalue.

I don't know why the outer map us a multimap (they are rarely useful) so the exampke just uses the first entry:

```
auto it = mymultimap.lower_bound(2);
if (it == mymultimap.end() || it->first != 2) {
    it = mymultimap.insert(
        std::make_pair(2, std::map<int, MyClass>())).first;
}
(*it)[1] = MyClassA;
```

(typed on a mobile device: there are probably typos but the overall approach should work).